# iOS Adding Initial Core Data file using UIManagedDocument, NOT appdelegate

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to load an initial database into my app so my core data db is not empty upon install. I'm now using this code:

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
            NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_InitialData", SQL_DATABASE_NAME] ofType:@"sqlite"];
            if (defaultStorePath) {
                    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
            }
    }
```

(from http://code.google.com/p/coredatalibrary/wiki/LoadingInitialData)

to try and load an initial sqlite file for my core data to use. It isn't working and my program differs from the type used in that link in a few ways.

It appears the tutorial uses a file created to "use core data", which I am not. I just didn't happen to learn it that way (watched the stanford cs193p videos) and instead I'm using UIManagedDocument and performing this code in my top view controller. Because of this, I've run into a few problems.

1. I loaded up my app to create the initial data base so I could save the file to use for initial values. Upon doing so, I found that the way things are saved are different from in the tutorial. For example, if my url for my UIManagedDocument is .../Documents/Test , then my database file is .../Documents/Test/Store Content/persistentStore, where "persistentStore" is the database file. For one thing, a "Store Content" directory has been added. In addition, the sqlite file is named persistentStore and has no file extension. When I open the file it says

> SQLite format 3���@  �����������������������������������������������������������������-‚%

on the top though (I'm not familiar with SQLite or any db format for that matter but I assume this means it is an sqlite file).

1. I save this "persistentStore" file to use to load into my app using the code above. Upon doing so, I found that copyItemAtPath:toPath:error: will not copy as I expect. For example, if the storePath is .../Documents/Test , then my sqlite file that I'm copying over becomes renamed to Test.sqlite and is located at .../Documents/ instead of copying my file to a location of .../Documents/Test/.

Because of this, when I try to open the UIManagedDocument at that url (.../Documents/Test) I get this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
'UIManagedDocument can only read documents that are file packages'
```

I've tried creating a directory to mimic the one created by core data before copying over my intial data (that is, I create the directories to have a path of .../Documents/Test/Store Content/ and then copy my initial data to be in the "Store Content" folder with a name of persistentStore) but that also doesn't work. UIManagedDocument can't open the document.

So how can I load in initial values to my core data db without having a project that is set to "use core data"? I have the (presumably) sqlite file with the initial data (when I open it and skim it it appears to have my initial values), so I just need to know how to copy it over properly so that I can still used UIManagedDocument to open the document and save via the UIManagedObjectContext.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my way of recreating the path created by core data worked. That is, creating the directories of .../Test/Store Content/ and copying the file as "persistentStore". My error was a small one. It was suppose to be **StoreContent** instead of "Store Content"; I added a space...